# How to approach nonlinear differential equations of second order?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

> Solve the given differential equations:
>
> a) $y'y''=2$, $y(0)=1$, $y'(0)=2$
>
> b) $y''- 3 y^2=0$,  $y(0)=2$, $y'(0)=4$.

I was thinking of turning that to 1st order differential equations by setting $y'=v$ and                $y''=v (dv/dy) $.

These exercises are from Elementary differential Equations of DiPrima.

Answer (score 4):

Hint:

a)

$$y' y'' = \frac12 \frac{d}{dt} (y')^2 $$

b)

Multiply both sides by $y'$.  Same hint as a).

**ADDENDUM**

Fuller solution to the above problems:

a)

$$\frac12 \frac{d}{dt} (y')^2 = 2 \implies (y')^2 = 4 t + C $$

$$y'(0)=2 \implies C=4$$

Then

$$y' = \pm 2 \sqrt{t+1} \implies y(t) = \pm \frac{4}{3} (t+1)^{3/2}+C'$$

$$y(0) = 1 \implies C' = \begin{cases} -\frac13 & + \\ \frac{5}{3} & - \end{cases} $$

b)

$$y' y'' = 3 y^2 y' \implies \frac12 \frac{d}{dt} (y')^2 = \frac{d}{dt} y^3 $$

or

$$\frac12 (y')^2 = y^3 + C$$

$$y'(0)=4 \quad y(0) = 2 \implies C=0 $$

Then

$$y' = \pm \sqrt{2} y^{3/2} $$

or

$$y^{-3/2} y' = \pm \sqrt{2} \implies 2 y^{1/2} = \pm \sqrt{2} t + C'$$

$$y(0)=2 \implies C' = \begin{cases} \sqrt{2} & + \\ 3 \sqrt{2} & - \end{cases} $$

Comment: In fact I was looking for a concrete answer.

Comment: That wasn't clear.  Can you not take it from the hint?

Comment: I am sorry but i still could not approach it. If you could help me @RonGordon

Comment: See more details above.